# Dynamically updating a plot in Haskell

Tags: haskell, plot

I have a program which performs a long-going calculation where the result is shown as a plot.
I am currently using [Chart-0.14](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/Chart) for this. I want to show the partial results, and update during calculations.
`Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Gtk.updateCanvas :: Renderable a -> DrawingArea -> IO Bool` seems to do that, but I do not find any way to get a DrawingArea from the plot. The function `renderableToWindow :: Renderable a -> Int -> Int -> IO ()` does not return anything (and furthermore it does not return before the window is closed).

I would like to do something like the following:

```
main = do
drawingArea = forkRenderableToWindow (toRenderable $ plotLayout $
                     plot [0,0.1..10] sin "sin(x)") 640 480
updateCanvas  (toRenderable $ plotLayout $  plot [0,0.1..10] sin "sin(x)") drawingArea
```

How should I do this? Would I need to reimplement the functions in `Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Gtk` with a version that returns the `DrawingArea` and in some way (how would I do this? forkIO?) returns immediately without closing the window?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`createRenderableWindow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Chart/0.14/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Gtk.html#v%3arenderableToWindow) and then you need to use the GTK operations to work on the given `Window` - I don't think the Chart package exports any higher level operations on `Window`s.

EDIT2: So ignore the below - it doesn't work even with GUI initilization.  My comment was a guess based on types.
EDIT:
Here is some example code.  Understand, I'm just piecing things together based on the types.  There might be better ways to do things if you ask someone who actually knows the library.

Below we use:

1. `createRenderableWindow` - this was the crux of my answer
2. `castToDrawingArea` - This is needed to get a `DrawingArea` from the `Window` type provided by GTK.  These casts are taking place of C++ OO inheritance, I think.
3. `widgetShowAll` - because we haven't actually displayed the window, we best do that.  I stole this function after looking at the source for `renderableToWindow`.
4. `updateCanvas` - I just saw this in the haddock documentation and figured it is why you wanted a `DrawingArea` in the first place.

Now for the code:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Gtk
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Renderable
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Misc.DrawingArea
import qualified Graphics.UI.Gtk as G

main = do
        win  <- createRenderableWindow emptyRenderable 400 400
        let draw = castToDrawingArea win
        G.widgetShowAll win
        updateCanvas emptyRenderable draw
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract the DrawingArea from the window, or do I need to get hold of it in another way?

Comment: @Hjulle I think you can use [`castToDrawingArea`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.0/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Misc-DrawingArea.html#t:DrawingArea) for this purpose.